# How To Hold A Value of 1 and Add 1 Every time It's Seen?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, how do you get 1 cell to hold a value of 1 if two other cells equal the same text; and then add 1 to that 1 cell again every time the other 2 cells repetitively equal the same text?

For example, if B129=I3, then D129 = 1. 1 now is to be held and never forgotten.

Then, if B129=I3 again, then D129 = 2. D129 can now repetitively increase by 1 over and over again as many times as B129=I3.

Comment: only with a script

Comment: Ok. I see. How would I design this script?

Comment: In my case, I3 can change to something else or it can change back to equal B129. So if I3 does equal B129 again, then it needs to add 1 again.

Answer (score 0):

So every time you change B129, update D129

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("My Sheet");
if  (e.range.getA1Notation() != 'B129')  return; //Something other than the cell you wanted changed
var x = ss.getRange("I3").getValue();
if (e.getValue() != x) return;  //B129 doesn't equal I3
var counter = ss.getRange("D129"); // cell reference
counter.setValue(counter.getValue() + 1);

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I am looking into this right now.

Comment: So I am getting an error. But I want to try something a little different now and perhaps much simpler. What if I want to create a function that says: If(B129=I3, drop  1 cell down between A2:A50, starting from A2)? And if B129 does not equal I3, then it stays where it left off.

Comment: What does "drop one cell down" mean

Comment: So for example, if B129=I3,it would drop from A2 to A3. But if B129 does not equal I3 again, then it would stay at A3 because that is where it left off. (So A3 could drop to A4 all the way down to A50, if B129 continues to equal I3).

Comment: I am looking at the code that you gave and the error that I get is: TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 10, file "Code"). Is 'e' undefined? How do I fix this error?

Comment: Did you change the sheet name to match your sheet?

Comment: @ J.G. Yes, I did.

Comment: There are only 7 lines in the snippet I write, which line is line 10 of your file?

Comment: Yes. You are right. There are only 7 lines. It became 10 lines because I tried to have Google Sheets recognize the function as an official name. So when I run the code again (without the extra lines I created), it says: TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code")

Comment: it is an onedit function, you can only test it by changing the cell you are talking about, you cannot test it from the ide page

Comment: Ok. I will check this out as soon as I can and let you know how it goes. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Hi @J.G. Thank you again for your help. So I understand that the function is supposed to work only on the spreadsheet. But if the code is giving me an error on the IDE page, it will not work on the spreadsheet. So the question is how do I fix the error occuring on line 3 where it says: "Cannot read property 'range' from undefined?
It appears that I3 = x; D129 = cell reference, but that B129 is not defined. So what does B129 equal?

Comment: I have attempted to say that var e = ss.getRange("B129"), but then it says that the getA1Notation section becomes an error. I think this is because the getA1Notation would be trying to cancel out the fact that var e = ss.getRange("B129"), but B129 will always equal B129.

Comment: So if I do: 

function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("M Numbers");
var e = ss.getRange("B129");
var x = ss.getRange("I3").getValue();
if (e.getValue() != x) return;  //B129 doesn't equal I3
var counter = ss.getRange("D129"); // cell reference
counter.setValue(counter.getValue() + 1);
}

It works, but if I make edits or changes on any other part of the spreadsheet, it continues to add 1 to D129 and that's not what I'm wanting. It's only supposed to add 1 to D129 if B129 and I3 equal each other.

Comment: thats because you overwrote e so that it always fires. What problem do you have if you use  the code example I wrote without changing it other than the spreadsheet name? "e" is supposed to be the cell that was edited. The script checks to see what cell it is and stops the function in line three if you edited something other than b129.

Comment: Hi J.G. The problem that I had, without editing anything other than the spreadsheet name,' is that the code did not run on the spreadsheet at all. Nothing happened, even if I performed what I needed to do on the actual spreadsheet, because the error continued to come up as: Cannot read property "range" from undefined.  (Line 3, file code).

Comment: Even if I used your code on a brand new Google sheet, this same error still comes up.

Comment: Hello @J.G. ! I wanted to reach back out again and to tell you thank you for your help. I eventually did get the code to work onEdit and I have everything running the way I want. Thank you again!